# (Non-)Isomorphism of (pre-)sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

I want to prove the following statement:

Let $f:F \to G$ be a homomorphism of sheaves. Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an open coverage of $X$, such that $f|{U_i}: F|U_i \to G|U_i$ is an isomorphism for all $i$.
Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

(A homomorphism of sheaves $f: F \to G$ is an indexed family $f = (f_U)_{U \subset X \text{ open}}$, $F(U) \to G(U)$, such that 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(U) @>{f_U}>> G(U)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
F(V) @>{f_V}>> G(V)
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative ($V \subset U$ open).
Isomorphism means: $f|_U$ is bijective for all $U$.)

**What I tried**

I looked at
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(U) @>{f_U}>> G(U)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
F(U_i \cap U) @>{}>> G(U_i \cap U)
\end{CD}
$$
and 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(U_i) @>{}>> G(U_i)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
F(U_i \cap U) @>{}>> G(U_i \cap U)
\end{CD}
$$

I picked $s,\tilde{s} \in F(U)$ with $s \neq \tilde{s}$ and tried to show $f_U(s) \neq f_U(\tilde{s})$ (for injective) by going through the diagrams.
However, I failed. Same for surjective.
Is this the right way to prove this?

The professor left this in the lecture unproved and I thought it is a good exercise to prove it since I'm not familiar with this yet.
Also the professor claims that the statement is not true if $F,G$ are only presheaves. Is that true?

Comment: It is true for sheaves and not true for presheaves. That is, in some the sense, the whole point about sheaves.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
That means there has to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof should go like this:

You can test an homomorphism of sheaves to be an isomorphism by looking at the stalks at each point. If $x \in U_i \subset X$ is given, the induced map $F_x \to G_x$ does not depend on whether you derive it from $f$ or from $f_{|U_i}$.

Here is a counterexample for the presheaf-case: Take $X$ to be the union of two discrete points and $F$ to be the constant presheaf $\mathbb Z$ on $X$. Let $G$ be the associated sheaf. The natural map $F \to G$ is not an isomorphism of presheaves but an isomorphism on both points.

Comment: That helped. I have a question though:

If $f|{U_i}$ is an isomorphism, than is $f_x: F_x \to G_x$ an isomorphism for all $x \in U_i$, too? If yes, then why? (If not, then I have to rethink my proof)

Comment: Passing to a stalk at a point is functorial, in particular isomorphism are preserved.